# How to keep the Makefile executing after fails in submakes but keep errors information

Tags: linux, unix, makefile, gnu-make

I have several Makefiles used for testing, main makefile looks like:

```
all: abc xyz

abc:
         $(MAKE) -C abc clean copy
         $(MAKE) -C abc -j 5 tests

xyz:
         $(MAKE) -C xyz clean copy
         $(MAKE) -C xyz -j 5 tests
```

"tests" targets in submakefiles looks like:

```
tests: test1 test2 ... testN
```

I run the main mk file: `make all`
The fails can occure in any place in submakefiles, but I want to keep the main mk file executing in spite of the fails. I need to run all "testN" in all submakefiles. I can use `-k` option, but I **need** to know information about every error occured during each run. Can not come with some solotions. Maybe there is a way to collect all infromation about fails runnin the main makefile with `-k`option, or maybe some other way exists..?

Comment: I don't understand the question: if you run `make -k`, as you've already suggested, it seems you'll get the behavior you describe.  Can you explain more clearly what about the `make -k` option is not working how you want?

Comment: If you have a test suite and this test suite is giving its output per `errout`, then IMHO this is an error in itself. `errout` is there to signal that the software you are using doesn't do what it should, i.e. in the case of a test that it can't run the test. Conveying that a test was executed but failed is a job for the `stdout` of a test suite.